# TCP Congestion Control Algorithm of OSX10.7

Tags: macos, tcp

How can I find out which algorithm OSX10.7 uses (NewReno, SACK, Tahoe...) and if possible, how can I change it?

Answer (score 2):

This Stack Overflow question should help: [How to load a different congestion control algorithm in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532372/how-to-load-a-different-congestion-control-algorithm-in-mac-os-x)

> The LEDBAT congestion control algorithm is built into OSX Lion
>   (10.7.X) and does not need to be compiled separately. I don't think it
>   would be possible to use LEDBAT in an earlier version of OSX without
>   alot of work. LEDBAT provides for 'background' transfers and may be
>   selected on a socket by setting the following socket option -
>   setsocketopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, O_TRAFFIC_CLASS, SO_TC_BK,
>   sizeof(int)). It also seems that the socket's traffic class may
>   affected by the DSCP value in the IP header.
>
> Additionally OSX has had the facility to load kernel modules for other
>   network protocols for some time using their Network Kernel Extensions
>   (NKE) - for example there is an NKE module that has been developed for
>   the SCTP protocol.

Alternatively, another related question might be useful: [How do you set the TCP congestion control algorithm on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12062/how-do-you-set-the-tcp-congestion-control-algorithm-on-os-x)

> According to
>   http://www.macgeekery.com/gspot/2006-03/mac_os_x_network_tuning_guide
>   you can actually modify the algorthims used by Mac OS X by using the
>   sysctl command, but you cannot use anything but the New Reno algorithm